# Paste multiple column values together by index

Tags: r, data.table, paste

I am needing to create a column called "combinations" in my data table that holds all values of the columns from column 4 to the end of my data table. I will use this line of code for multiple data tables and the number of columns will vary from data table to data table, so I do not always know the index number of the last column. The start will always be column 4.

I know of functions that work just fine using multiple column names, but not using multiple column indices. Does anyone know how to do this?

Example of something that would work using column names and not column indices:

```
mycols<-c("apple", "orange", "banana")
data[, combinations:=paste(mycols, sep=", ")]
```

Example of something I've tried using column indices that does not work:

```
ncols<-ncol(data)
my_cols <- data[ , c(4:ncols)] 
data[, combinations:=paste(mycols, sep=", ")]
```

Example data

```
id  number  day apple  orange  banana  
1   35      2   red    orange  yellow
2   12      3   red    NA      yellow
3   47      5   NA     orange  yellow
```

The final result I'm trying to accomplish

```
id  number  day apple  orange  banana  combinations
1   35      2   red    orange  yellow  red, orange, yellow
2   12      3   red    NA      yellow  red, NA, yellow
3   47      5   NA     orange  yellow  NA, orange, yellow
```

Answer (score 4):

We may need `do.call`

```
library(data.table)
data[, combinations := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = ", ")), .SDcols = 4:ncols]
```

-output

```
> data
   id number day apple orange banana        combinations
1:  1     35   2   red orange yellow red, orange, yellow
2:  2     12   3   red   <NA> yellow     red, NA, yellow
3:  3     47   5  <NA> orange yellow  NA, orange, yellow
```

---

Or use `unite`, which can remove the `NA` elements with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  unite(combinations, all_of(4:ncols), sep = ", ", na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
    id number day        combinations apple orange banana
1:  1     35   2 red, orange, yellow   red orange yellow
2:  2     12   3         red, yellow   red   <NA> yellow
3:  3     47   5      orange, yellow  <NA> orange yellow
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(id = 1:3, number = c(35L, 12L, 47L), day = c(2L, 
3L, 5L), apple = c("red", "red", NA), orange = c("orange", NA, 
"orange"), banana = c("yellow", "yellow", "yellow")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
setDT(data)
```

Comment: Why does this not work: `data$combination <- paste(data[,4:6], sep = ", ")
data`.

Comment: @TarJae `paste` takes variadic argument `paste(..., ` where we have to specify each argument separately `paste(data[[4]], data[[5]], data[[6]], sep = ", ")`.  Other option is to use `do.call` for variadic arguments or in some functions (`Reduce`)

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, using `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(combinations = list(c_across(4:ncol({{df}})))) %>% 
  data.frame()
  id number day apple orange banana        combinations
1  1     35   2   red orange yellow red, orange, yellow
2  2     12   3   red   <NA> yellow     red, NA, yellow
3  3     47   5  <NA> orange yellow  NA, orange, yellow
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, number = c(35L, 12L, 47L), day = c(2L, 
3L, 5L), apple = c("red", "red", NA), orange = c("orange", NA, 
"orange"), banana = c("yellow", "yellow", "yellow")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```